# How to return the address of inner struct given pointer to outter struct in c

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-address

How can I return the address of the target if i have the following struct and the prototype for the function is also as follows

```
struct inner{
 int foo;
};

struct outter{
 struct inner innerStruct[100];
};

struct inner * foo1(int target){
}
```

NOTE**
I don't need the algorithm to find the target, I just want to know how to return the address of the target if found.

Comment: Where do you have a pointer to the outer structure? `foo1` is passed `target`, which is an `int`, not a pointer.

Comment: sorry, it's supposed to be struct inner * foo1( struct outter * out, int target)

Answer (score 2):

If `out`  is a pointer to a `struct outter`, then `out->innerStruct` is the array `innerStruct` inside that structure, and `out->innerStruct[i]` is element `i` of that array, and `&out->innerStruct[i]` is the address of that element.